# Cleanest way to filter objects before adding to a collection?

Tags: java, lambda, coding-style, java-stream

```
  private List<BusinessObject> createList(int property1, List<String> filenames) {
    List<BusinessObject> objectList = new ArrayList();
    filenames.forEach(filename -> {
        BusinessObject businessObj = parseObject(filename);
        if (businessObj.getProperty1() == property1) {
            objectList.add(businessObj);
        }
    });
    return objectList;
  }
```

I feel like there must be a more idiomatic or Java 8-ish solution out there, such as

```
filesnames.forEach(fileName -> parseObject(fileName)).(some method that takes the output of parseObject)
```

Comment: you could use `filenames.stream().map(this::parseObject).filter(object -> Objects.equals(property1, object.getProperty1())).collect(Collectors.toList());`

Comment: ..What is `key`?

Comment: That is much better, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The exact stream equivalent would be:

```
return filenames.stream()
         .map(filename -> parseObject(filename))
         .filter(o -> o.getProperty1() == property1)
         .collect(Collectors.toCollection(ArrayList::new));
```

Comment: why not simply `Collectors.toList`?

Comment: @Naman Once someone told me that "to be sure, in case the implementation of toList changes" , idk if Ousmane thinks like this :D